# Manage ID for tasks not processed yet in queue

Tags: architecture, rabbitmq, queue, message-queue

I'm looking for tutorials/articles that explain how to maintain ID for items in queue that were not processed yet.

I am looking for a few tutorials to get more perspectives and be exposed to more ideas, because we know that there is no one solution’s fits all.

I’ve been looking on google but I’m probably typing the wrong words because I didn’t find any article talking about that.

A description of what I’m looking for is something like this.

The user clicks on a button, it sends some payload to a queue, but it will take some seconds/minutes to be processed.

So we have two alternatives.

First, give an ID to the user, but we all know that the user will keep pressing F5 to see if the status has changed.

Second, don’t give the user a number to see the status, the user will most likely repeat that process and will be opening new tasks (because if the user doesn't get feedback it will likely be seen as an error).

I’m interested in the first option.

Different strategies of managing this ID.

Do I keep it in a DB like redis, or a relational DB?
Is it possible or advised to query the queue directly?
Is it scalable horizontally?
If the ID is generated only when the task is processed, do I pre create the ID to insert in the task or keep many ids for different steps?
If this ID is generated by a third party API that I do not control?

I know that this type of problem was already solved by smarter people than me, so I don’t want to recreate the wheel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest to is an approach in two phases:

1. Keep your customer updated about the status of his query. Read the section *Asynchronous operations* from this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design).

> Sometimes a POST, PUT, PATCH, or DELETE operation might require
> processing that takes a while to complete. If you wait for completion
> before sending a response to the client, it may cause unacceptable
> latency. If so, consider making the operation asynchronous. Return
> HTTP status code 202 (Accepted) to indicate the request was accepted
> for processing but is not completed.
>
> You should expose an endpoint that returns the status of an
> asynchronous request, so the client can monitor the status by polling
> the status endpoint. Include the URI of the status endpoint in the
> Location header of the 202 response.

2. Remove your message in the queue when the process in finish.

While reading your message, you can dynamically generate and ID by using a `UUID` to identify your payload. The ID will be affected to predefined field in your payload.
I guess your message in the queue has enough information you need to process it. As your processing is not finish, you should keep the message in the queue and delete it after the process is finished.

Comment: It was very helpful and already added some things from the [Asynchronous Request-Reply pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/async-request-reply) presented on the article.